# What is AM-CM inequality?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

There's AM-GM inequality. But I've bumped into AM-CM inequality in official solutions for IMO 2018 problems. Here:

[image]
This is A7 problem, solution 1 from here: https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2018SL.pdf

I attempted to use AM-GM inequality in case they simply misspelled, but AM-GM doesn't seem to work here.

Any ideas?

Comment: CM probably stands for cubic mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AM-CM inequality likely denotes the [Arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) - [Cubic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_mean) inequality which is a specific instance of the [Generalized mean inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality). This inequality follows directly from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Given what is going on, what they are using is the fact that if a function $f:I\to\mathbb R$ is convex (here $I\subset\mathbb R$ is an interval), and $x,y\in I$, then
$$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$
or, equivalently, if $f:I\to\mathbb R$ is concave, then 
$$\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}\leq f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right).$$
Some people take the statement as the definition of a convex function, and then a function $f$ is concave if $-f$ is convex.

I imagine the "C" in AM-CM stands for either "convex" or "concave".

Comment: See also [Jensen's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 2):

Elementary approach: no Jensen's inequality or AM-GM inequality (or even AM-CM inequality). BTW I warmly recommend the [REAL Shortlist 2018](https://kosgeza.web.elte.hu/imo2018/TheRealShortlist2018.pdf).

It suffices to show that if $a,b\geq 0$ then 
$$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^3\leq \frac{a^3+b^3}{2}\tag{1}$$
which is equivalent to 
$$0\leq a^3+b^3-a^2b-ab^2=(a+b)(a-b)^2$$ 
that trivially holds.

Then apply (1) by letting $a=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+t+14}{7}}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{\frac{y+t+14}{7}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the REAL Shortlist! :)

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be using [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) with (Wikipedia's notation) $x_1 = \frac{x+t+14}{7}$, $x_2=\frac{y+z+14}{7}$ and $a_1 = a_2 = 1$ and $\varphi(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$.